# Unable to access Ionic application ts files in browser

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm working on ionic angular project and i cannot debug the code on web browser cause all am seeing is compiled js files and webpack is not available.
I'm using `ionic Cordova run browser` as I'm using app preference in the application and `ionic serve` does not support platform specific plugins, Has anyone experienced this before. any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you just run ng start and debug it outside ionic/cordova ?

Comment: no, it gives an error because it can't access Cordova app preference